# Moving resources from one Azure account to another

Tags: azure

A company that we hired to develop or software created an azure account where they have our database, API, etc. Recently we decided to have our own azure account and our plan is to move all the resources that are on the vendor azure account to our own.

It is possible to move all the services from the vendor account to ours? if so can you guys point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The boundary for resources in Azure is the "Subscription". All you need to do is change the subscription for the resources.

In the Azure Portal, select the Resource Group with the resources that you want to move to your control. Then change the Subscription ID to yours.

You cannot move all types of resources. Some you will need to recreate. This link provides more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#services-that-enable-move